# How to output parts of a string array from text file from session in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, validation, session

My page lets the user choose a list of courses that they wish to attend from a list opened up by the .php script. The choices the user picks are set to an array of check boxes called courses[]. One the Result.php, the choices chosen are sent through a RegEx to extract the course names and the hours that each course requires. The course name is only outputted while the hours are added up to show the total hours needed each week.

**My problem is, I have fixed all syntax, but nothing is returned when I call out my printf format. I tried to var_dump($courses) and ($courseLine) and it came out to NULL and NULL. I think I have a piece of logic error on Registration.php but I cant find where.**
*Below is my Result.php and I will include a sample of the course list text file*

```
<table><tr><th>Courses</th><th>hours per Week</th></tr>
<?php
                $courses = $_GET['courses'];
                $courseHoursRegEx = "/\s[0-9]{1,2}\shrs/w/";//needs work
                $courseNameRegEx = "/[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{0,1}\s?/[a-zA-Z]{3,40}/";

    function GetCourseHours($couseLine)
    {
        if(!preg_match($courseHoursRegEx, $courseLine))
            {
                return $courseHour;
            }
        $totalHours += $courseHour;
    }
    function GetCourseName($courseLine)
    {
        if(!preg_match($courseNameRegEx, $courseLine))
            {
                return $courseInfo;
            }
    }
                foreach($courses as $course)
                        {
                            $theCourse = GetCourseName($course);
                            $theHours = GetCourseHours($course);
                        }
                for($i = 1; $i <= $courses; ++$i)
                {
                    printf("<tr><td>\%</td><td>\%</td></tr>", $theCourse, $theHours);
                }
?>
                <tr>
                <th>Total Hours</th><td><?php echo $totalHours ?>        </td></tr>
                </table>
```

**Here is my starting page, so you have an idea what values are worked with (I did not include the validation functions due the the length of script.)**

```
    </table>
<?php 
    $courseFile = fopen("CourseList.txt", "r");
    $courseHoursRegEx = "/\s[0-9]{1,2}\shrs/w/";
    $courseNameRegEx = "/[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{0,1}\s?/[a-zA-Z]{3,40}/";

    while(!feof($courseFile))
        {
            $courseLine = fgets($courseFile);
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='courses[]' value='$courseLine'/> $courseLine <br />";
        }
        fclose($courseFile);
    function GetCourseHours($courseLine)
    {
        if(!preg_match($courseHoursRegEx, $courseLine))
            {
                return $courseLine;
            }
    }
    function GetCourseName($courseLine)
    {
        if(!preg_match($courseNameRegEx, $courseLine))
            {
                return $courseLine;
            }
    }
?>
```

**Here is a sample of what the text file looks like with course information**

```
CON8101 Residential Building/Estimating 16 hrs/w 
CON8411 Construction Materials I 4 hrs/w 
CON8430 Computers and You 4 hrs/w 
MAT8050 Geometry and Trigonometry 4 hrs/w 
SAF8408 Health and Safety 5 hrs/w
```

Comment: check the below, see if that simplifies your getting at the course hours.

Comment: @Dave 
the variable $text would be a line of the text file, correct? The $matches variable would be how I output pieces of the line I need, for instance, I need the course hours so I can call out $matches[3] and it will come out with the hours to be used in my table. Just clarifying, I have never used that way before.

Comment: What is this supposed to mean `$totalHours =+ $courseHour;`?

Comment: @shakabra oops, Mistyped when I was formating. It is suppose to mean when I have extracted the course Hours from string using my regex, I add the numbers up to get total hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while not specifically answering your question, try using the following regex on each line in your file;

```
preg_match('/(?P<courseid>[A-Z0-9]+) (?P<coursename>.*) (?P<coursehours>\d+) hrs/',$text,$matches);
```

this will create an array `$matches` in this case which you can then reference the elements more inately

```
Array
(
    [0] => CON8101 Residential Building/Estimating 16 hrs
    [courseid] => CON8101
    [1] => CON8101
    [coursename] => Residential Building/Estimating
    [2] => Residential Building/Estimating
    [coursehours] => 16
    [3] => 16
)
```

which will simplify your code and addition functions immensely.

Answer (score 0):

[`=+` is not a valid php operator try `+=`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) If your using numbers try `+=` if strings use `.=`. Hope that works.